# android: InputConnection from different thread.

Tags: java, android, multithreading, input

Does the commitText() method of the android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection allowed to be called from different thread than UI thread?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is not really a straight answer for your question but if you want to access the UI thread through another thread you can always use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Override [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) with your normal thread task and override [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) with the tasks that will need access to the UI thread. Whenever you need to do your tasks inside [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) you call [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) from [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29).